# javascript find element from array and remove few from it

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array like below:

```
var arr = [ {RoomId:1, RoomName: 'ABC'},
            {RoomId:1, RoomName: 'ABC'},
            {RoomId:1, RoomName: 'ABC'},
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
           ];
```

My requirement is something like

1. Find particular room with RoomId say RoomId = 1.
2. Remove last few elements from it like remove last 2 elements with RoomId = 1.

So my final array would be like:

```
var arr = [ {RoomId:1, RoomName: 'ABC'},                
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
            {RoomId:2, RoomName: 'XYZ'},
          ];
```

Comment: Just so you know, that's a JavaScript array. It has no connection with jQuery at all.

Comment: No apology needed! It's a common point of confusion. I just wanted to help you identify which is which. In any case I'm glad you asked the question, because I hadn't heard of the linq.js library that Anik mentioned - it looks very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to maintain this kind of task

Like this

> Find particular room with RoomId say RoomId = 1.

Code

```
var data =Enumerable.From(arr).Where(function(x){return x.RoomId===1;}).ToArray();
```

> Remove last few elements from it like remove last 2 elements with
>   RoomId = 1.

```
var data =Enumerable.From(arr).Where(function(x){return x.RoomId===1;}).OrderByDescending(function(x){return x.RoomId;}).Skip(2);

arr=data.OrderBy(function(x){return x.RoomId;}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful, is it free to use and works on all browsers ? Also I forgot to mention that I don't want to make a new array. I want to do everything on same array.

Comment: If you wanna hold on same variable your data will be lost

Comment: The last line in your code, I think it is retaining the same array right?

Comment: Yes. it's replacing same array

Comment: data.OrderBy(...).toArray is not a function ... I am getting this error,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82044/discussion-between-pratik-and-anik-islam-abhi).

Comment: Is there any way to retain the same array please.

Comment: you can clone same array before replace

Comment: `var cloneData=arr.slice();`

Comment: But what to do of this cloneData.

Comment: This solution is good but I am not able to achieve my desired result, the array is replaced.

Comment: it's about logic. how you hold your data and what to do with it :)

Comment: Yes i understand but somehow I am not getting to retain the same array and remove the elements as asked in question.

Comment: Can you please help me in getting this ?

Comment: I am in office now. I will post a fiddle after reaching home.

Answer (score 0):

I developed logic for your query like

```
var destArr=[];
var flag=false;
var count=0;
for(i in arr)
{ 
    if(arr[i].RoomId==1 && flag==false)
    {
        flag = true;
        destArr[count++] = arr[i];              
    }
    else if(flag==true && arr[i].RoomId!=1)
    {
        destArr[count++] = arr[i];              
    }                                   
}   
console.log(destArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oz6hw8qd/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I don't want to make a new array. I want to do everything on same array.